# Python - Showing console output

Tags: python

Right now I have a command which allows you to apply changes to the local files on my hosting server. Is there a way to make the bot send `await ctx.send(...)` the output of the `git reset` command to Discord?
Normally the output looks like this:

```
HEAD is now at f8dd7fe Slash Commands/Pull Feature/JSON Changes!
```

This is my current command:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Bot Manager')
async def gitpull(ctx):
    typebot = config['BotType']
    if typebot == "BETA":
        os.system("git fetch --all")
        os.system("git reset --hard origin/TestingInstance")
        await ctx.send("I have attempted to *pull* the most recent changes in **TestingInstance**")
    elif typebot == "STABLE":
        os.system("git fetch --all")
        os.system("git reset --hard origin/master")
        await ctx.send("I have attempted to *pull* the most recent changes in **Master**")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) module instead of `os.system`.  That will allow you to capture the subprocess's output.

Something like:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Bot Manager')
async def gitpull(ctx):
    typebot = config['BotType']
    output = ''
    if typebot == "BETA":
        p = subprocess.run("git fetch --all", shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
        output += p.stdout
        p = subprocess.run("git reset --hard origin/TestingInstance", shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
        output += p.stdout
        await ctx.send(f"I have attempted to *pull* the most recent changes in **TestingInstance**\n{output}")
    elif typebot == "STABLE":
        p = subprocess.run("git fetch --all", shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
        output += p.stdout
        p = subprocess.run("git reset --hard origin/master", shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
        output += p.stdout
        await ctx.send(f"I have attempted to *pull* the most recent changes in **Master**\n{output}")
```